Executor going OOM if cardinality of .partitionBy columns is 1 in Scala-Spark Job
Problem Statement: I have an s3 path that contains json .bin.gz data in dt and hr partitioned format. For a single day it contains 2B+ records and the compressed size is around 200GB. So uncompressed it might exceed 500GB. I am reading it, then inner joining with another very small broadcasted dataset (also in s3) to populate another column and writing it back to s3 in Parquet format using week, dt partitions. This ran fine in our dev environment where data volume is less but failed in Prod. The job is running in a Kubernetes cluster.
df.partitionBy("wk", "dt").write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3a/bucket-name/xxx/")

Dynamic partition overwrite mode is set to true.
Issue: The size of df is huge as mentioned earlier. The partition columns wk and dt will have only 1 distinct value each i.e., cardinality is 1.
When I am doing this, I see errors like the below while it is trying to write it to s3:
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: ResultStage 14 (save at S3DataSink.scala:49) has failed the maximum allowable number of times: 4. Most recent failure reason:

org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0 partition 0

The API gave the following message: The node was low on resource: ephemeral-storage. Container spark-kubernetes-executor was using 669088Ki, which exceeds its request of 0.
24/09/13 10:53:26 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 14.3 (TID 10281) (10.2.164.14 executor 16): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 16 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason:

INFO DAGScheduler: Resubmitting ShuffleMapStage 13 (save at S3DataSink.scala:49) and ResultStage 14 (save at S3DataSink.scala:49) due to fetch failure

What I tried -> Increased the number of executor instances from 12 to 30 and executor memory from 16GB to 22GB but the exact same error occurred again.
What I am thinking to try ->
Adding a repartition before partitionBy:
df.repartition(200).partitionBy("wk", "dt").write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3a/bucket-name/xxx/")

Or
Avoid partitionBy altogether, and directly write it to the desired folder path:
df.repartition(200).write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3a/bucket-name/xxx/wk=yyy/dt=zzz/")

I think since the cardinality of my partitionBy columns is 1, is it taxing one of the executors and it's going OOM? Is ephemeral storage coming to picture because of this?
I want some pointers on this as code change to Prod is a lengthy process in our org and requires multiple levels of approval. So I don't want to make a change and have it fail again in production.
Why am I partitioning if the cardinality of partition columns is 1? In the next step we will aggregate the week's data into a weekly table in a rolling fashion. So I need the folder hierarchy to read from the appropriate partition. E.g., if week 37 consists of 9th September to 15th September, On 10th September the week 37 table will contain only 9th September's aggregated data, on 11th Sept it will include 9th and 10th Sept aggregated data, and so on.
